# What is the difference between type of namespace declaration

Tags: c#, asp.net, namespaces, global-variables, declaration

I have small doubt about the namespace declarations.

We can declare  the namespace by two types. like, with `using` keyword and without `using` keyword

**Point A**

```
public List<**SharedModel.DisplayModel.AttendanceDisplayModel**> GetAttendanceById(string userId)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
```

**My application name is `TravelManagement`. but my point A is does not take `TravelManagement`.**

**Point B**

```
using TravelManagement.SharedModel.DisplayModel;

 public List<AttendanceDisplayModel> GetAttendanceById(string userId)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
```

**My application name is `TravelManagement`. but my point B take `TravelManagement` . `Why Why?`**

See the namespace declaration about **SharedModel.DisplayModel.AttendanceDisplayModel**.

What was the difference between the two type of namespace declarations?

Actually I know some basic ideas

1 - It's helps to reduce the code when declare the namespace in globally.

2- also `using` keyword helps to automatically closed the object connections.

but my  namespace class  is did't create any object's, ten why I need `using`?

If you have any ideas, then please bring to me.

Welcomes You!

Comment: [using (directive)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/sf0df423.aspx) is different from [using (statement)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/yh598w02.aspx).

Comment: Okay dude, What was the difference for my sample's?

Comment: Importing namespace tells you compiler to refer class and method definitions in that namespace. If you have same method in two of your referred namespace, it will throw an ambiguity error. At that time you need to explicitely specify your namespace as you did in point A.

Comment: You're using [using (directive)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/sf0df423.aspx). It's a bit hard to understand what your actual problem is. If you have a namespace `SharedModel.DisplayModel` which contains a class `AttendanceDisplayModel`, then the directive `using SharedModel.DisplayModel;` will allow you to access `AttendanceDisplayModel` directly, without always having to specify the fully qualified class name `SharedModel.DisplayModel.AttendanceDisplayModel`. This assumes that there is no other class `AttendanceDisplayModel` in any of the other "used" namespaces.

Comment: The other [using (statement)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/yh598w02.aspx) is just for easier handling of [IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.idisposable.aspx) objects. This is probably what you meant by "2- [...] automatically close". But it does not seem like you're working with an IDisposable here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you use namespaces to distinguish methods, members, etc. with the same name(!) from each other.

Imagine one of your friends has also written a AttendanceDisplayModel. With namespaces you know which model should be called ;)

Comment: Well, But actually i don't get a detailed answer. Please ready my full questions. Am asking about why we use `using`,  why project name does not take in the point B declaration,.